# Impedir que o usuário use a janela da mainwindow enquanto outra window estiver aberta

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf, progress-bar, mvvm

---

Tenho uma aplicação em WPF seguindo o padrão MVVM e em certa parte da aplicação eu mostro uma ProgressBar que implementei em uma view separada para o usuário e, enquanto essa progressBar estiver rodando, precisaria que o usuário fosse impossibilitado de mexer em qualquer outra janela, assim como o método "ShowDialog()" faz porém, se eu exibo a progressBar usando o ShowDialog() a main app para de fazer o processo pois fica esperando o Result da minha view...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está a parte do Código em que chamo a progressBar

```
_progressBar = new PackProgressBar("Packing",BasicVariableCollection.Count - 1);
_progressBar.Show();
```

Onde "PackProgressBar" é o nome da minha classe da View da progressbar, que é da classe "Window"

Comment: Talvez você possa trabalhar com Threads. O processo roda numa thread separada enquanto a thread principal fica responsável somente em trabalhar os eventos das janelas do seu programa. Essa aproximação é a mais recomendada quando temos trabalhos que devem ser executados em background mas não devem paralizar as respostas das janelas. 

Costumo trabalhar c/ BackgroundWorker no WinForms, mas aparentemente as boas práticas para WPF dizem p/ usar uma modelagem de Threading na aplicação, veja a refêrencia do MSDN: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui chegar a uma solução para o problema, utilizando a propriedade "IsEnabled" da mainwindow assim, setando essa proprierdade para "false" ao chamar a progressbar e depois para "true" no RunWorkerCompleted da task assincrona

```
 _progressBar = new PackProgressBar("Packing", BasicVariableCollection.Count - 1);
 _progressBar.Show();
 System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = false;
```

e

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.IsEnabled = true;
_progressBar.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar `Form.ShowDialog`.

`ShowDialog()`método em vez de `Show()`quando você exibe o formulário filho.

Comment: O método "ShowDialog()" faz com que o metodo fique "Trancado" até ter um Result, e assim o meu "LongRunningProcess" trava e nao segue adiante